# Bash shell commanding to vpn connection from command line

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a bash shell (very first time) so that I can auto connect to a VPN server. I have never written a bash script before. can anyone tell me what command syntax I need for this?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hi would you like to connect to vpn labs? Yes or No"
sleep 2
read answer
$connect = "rdesktop -u offsec -p ******** 192.168.***.***"
if $ answer != "No" then $connect
else
exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the right command to connect vpn, read the following. https://askubuntu.com/questions/57339/connect-disconnect-from-vpn-from-the-command-line.

First, run this in the terminal and see if it works. `rdesktop -u offsec -p ******** 192.168.***.***"`

Then you want to watch your syntax for your bash script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -e -p "Hi would you like to connect to vpn labs? Yes or No " answer
sleep 2

if [ $answer != "No" ];
    then rdesktop -u offsec -p ******** 192.168.***.***
else
    exit
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise that you:

1. Learn the syntax of the main shell constructs (if-statement in
   your case). You may use `man bash` and `help if` for that.
2. run each line in the shell and see if it's properly written or not, and
   whether it does what you want or not.

Quick observations:

1. There is no '`$`' when you are setting the variable. It's used
   when you reference the variable.
2. There is no space between `$` and the variable name.